# Why do we have to invoke await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User) per action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

To be honest, I don't understand how an asp.net-core-based web application works. Right now I am attempting to figure out a little by little how it works behind the scene.

Let's consider the default template with `Individual User Account` selected. More precisely in the `ManageController` class as follows.

```
namespace StackOverflow.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class ManageController : Controller
    {
        // others are trimmed for the sake of simplicity 

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EnableAuthenticator(EnableAuthenticatorViewModel model)
        {
            // ..........

            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            // ........
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ResetAuthenticator()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            //.......
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateRecoveryCodes()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            // ..........
        }        
}
```

## Question

The statement

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

occurs almost in each action method.

Why do we have to invoke `await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` per action method? Why don't we make it as a class property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a class property, you'd need an *asynchronous property*. This isn't possible in C# - Stephen Cleary goes into a good amount of detail on this topic [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html).

> This is a purposeful design decision, because “asynchronous properties” is an oxymoron. Property getters should return current values; they should not be kicking off background operations. Also, the semantics behind an “asynchronous setter” are not at all clear.

Although you *could* block on the async code, it's not recommended. There's another post from Stephen Cleary on that topic [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html).

> However, you shouldn’t. Because the moment you block on asynchronous code, you’re giving up every benefit of asynchronous code in the first place. The enhanced scalability of asynchronous handlers is nullified as soon as you block a thread.

Comment: Besides asynchronous issue, is there any other reason? In my mental model, an asp.net web app are shared among many users so a user request corresponds to an action method call, as a result, globally defined user does not make sense. Is it correct?

Comment: The `User`passed into `GetUserAsync` is a property of the controller - For each individual request that comes in, there is a new instance of the controller that therefore has its own `User`. If `GetUser` as a sync operation was an option, you could just use a property to wrap up that call if desired.

Comment: Yes, one HTTP request generally maps to one `ActionMethod` call, on a *new* instance of the controller.  Any "global" state stored at the controller level would be lost between requests. So while you *can* store it there, there is no benefit over storing it as a local variable within the `ActionMethod`

Comment: It would be theoretically possible to use an `IAsyncActionFilter` to populate a `User` property in a way that you don't have to manually call it yourself in every `ActionMethod`.  That's getting a little advanced though.

Comment: @BradleyUffner and Kirk Larkin: Do you have any recommended resources (documentation, books, etc) that can help me get better understanding about how asp.net core works?

Comment: If you want to try out the `IAsyncActionFilter`, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#implementation).

Comment: The [ASP.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?tabs=aspnetcore1x) as a whole are a good resource to start with.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: I need an explanation how a single (or multiple) asp.net core(s) web app work(s) to serve multiple requests. Thank you.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: Of course you can await a property, it just can't be marked as async for obvious reasons. A `public Task AspNetUser => _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` property compiles file and can be awaited via `await this.AspNetUser`, but there is no real reasons to do that (also never seen it being used).

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity: HTTP by its very nature is stateless. Each request is independent of the previous one. On every request new instances of the controller, DbContext (ORM) etc. get created and no values are persisted. For persistence one has to use sessions (only in MVC; not in API calls - they are to be stateless) or singleton caches. But since you seem to be very beginner, I would recommend first looking in Wikipedia how HTTP works in general and then going through the tutorials of ASP.NET Core docs, before starting a real application